# Why would you have a string >= '0' condition in PHP?

Tags: php, plsql, checksum

As part of an integration against a third party service I need to calculate a check digit.  I have been given a PHP snippet to show the algorithm but I need to implement it in pl/sql.  The PHP snippet (taken from [here](http://pangaliit.ee/en/settlements-and-standards/check-digit-calculator-of-domestic-account-number)) is:

```
function arvutaViitenumber($nr){
     $nr = (string)$nr;
     $kaal = array(7,3,1);
     $sl = $st = strlen($nr);
     $total = 0;
     while($sl > 0 and substr($nr, --$sl, 1) >='0'){
         $total += substr($nr, ($st-1)-$sl, 1)*$kaal[($sl%3)];
     }
     $kontrollnr = ((ceil(($total/10))*10)-$total);
     return $nr.$kontrollnr;
}
```

I understand most of it except the `substr($nr, --$sl, 1) >='0'`condition in the loop.  There are two things I do not understand about this:

1. The main body of the loop takes each digit in order from the start.  Why then have a condition where the loop exits before processing the nth digit from the start based on the state of the nth digit from the end?
2. When comparing a single-character string as greater or equal string `'0'` can the condition ever be false?  In my tests it is always true, even if the string compared is a character not a number.

Question 1 is more of accademic intrest.  My real interest is question 2 and how I will  implement this check in the pl/sql version (or if I even need to?)

Comment: `var_dump("\n" >= "0")` ⇒ `bool(false)`

Comment: `! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . /` - also false

Comment: @FDL Sure, I just gave one of examples. Actually, `substr($nr, --$sl, 1) >='0'` is nearly the “is alphanumeric” test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** Well, think how the reverse would go.

```
 $st = strlen($nr);
 $sl = $total = 0;
 while($sl < strlen($nr) and substr($nr, ++$sl, 1) >='0'){
```

Notice the `strlen` in the while loop - bad practice. Although in PHP it's fast, in most programming languages this is horrible for performance. The alternative would be to use another variable, which would be reduntant.

So the best option for both lazyness and performance is to start from the end.

**2.** As far as I can tell, the only purpose of that string comparison is to make sure the position in the ASCII table is higher or equal to `'0'` ASCII no. 48). First, check the http://www.asciitable.com/

Then take a look at the following tests I did:

```
var_dump(' ' >= '0'); // false // space has ASCII no 32
var_dump('(' >= '0'); // false // ASCII no 47
var_dump('A' >= '0'); // true // ASCII no 65
var_dump('[' >= '0'); // true // ASCII no 71
```

So it's almost an alphanumeric test, as @mudasobwa mentioned.

Comment: Thanks.  That makes sense. So basically an `is not null` should suffice then.  I'm still confused why we care if a different charact is null - I could understand checking that the current character is not null, but this checking backwards is weird, in my opinion

Comment: @Adam: Added an answer to #1 as well :) Pretty much personal opinion I guess

Comment: Yeah, the reverse I could understand.  We take each digit in turn buyt when we get to a digit which is empty of punctuation we stop looping.  I don't understand only processing the first 3 digits in a ten-character string because the 7th character is punctuation...

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You should not try to find any logic in the algorhytm here: it’s kinda hash function and it’s goal is to give the same “verifying” value on same input. Take a look at Java’s [`String::hashCode()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode%28%29) implementation, for instance.

**2.** They decide to **bring an additional entropy** by stopping a loop when the n-th from the end **is not alphanumeric**. Nothing more. There is no hidden sense.

Comment: Ok.  I can buy that. I'm not convinced this way of adding entropy is a good idea - it means that the checkdigit for any string ending in punctuation will always be 0 - but that's their call.

Comment: Since I have no clue about real application, I can’t say anything meaningful. E. g. they might want to “group” all the sentences (ending with dot,) to filter on them later.

Answer (score 0):

> When comparing a single-character string as greater or equal string
>   '0' can the condition ever be false? In my tests it is always true,
>   even if the string compared is a character not a number.

`"<string>" >= '0'` is false, if `<string>` is either empty or null or negative number, but true if 0 or '0' or other

Dont be fooled by the types here, `>=` will (in contrast to `>==`) default to / cast to some type. (and since its php, its impossible to remember which, at least for me)

Edit: also `false >= '0'` is true - this might be intended here

Comment: I know `>=` can cast - but I thought it only did so if they types of the two things compared differed.  In this case both are strings so it shouldn't cast (I thought)

Comment: @Adam: substr will return `false` on failure, which is not a string

Comment: @Adam: You are correct. String comparison won't cast anything.

Comment: @birdspider: very true - except that the way the substrings are constructed in this case they will always exist.  Also, since it is a single character string it cannot be a negative number.  So we are left with empty/null strings

Comment: “this might be intended here” you must be kidding.

Comment: @mudasobwa: why, while there are substring do stuff, and a last time for when there aren't any left - both sides of the while(A and B) could terminate - or am I missing something

Comment: @birdspider JIC: the `substr` in the snippet given **never** returns **FALSE**.